# Python 3.4 parsing HTML

Tags: python, parsing, html-parsing

I am trying to write my own HTML parser that takes in a URL, converts the HTML at that URL to a string, and then assigns tags and words to an array.

```
import urllib.request

#print("Enter URL")
#url = input()
#print("The site you chose was %s" % url)

response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex14.html')
data = response.read()
text = data.decode('utf-8')

def add_word(w):
    word_database.append(w)
    word = ""

tag = False
word_database=[]
word= ""

for c in text:
    if tag == False:
        if c == "<":
            word += c
            tag = True
        elif  c != " ":
            word += c
        elif word != "" and c == " ":
            add_word(word)
        else:
            print("parsing error")
    elif tag == True:
        if c == ">":
            word += c
            add_word(word)
            tag = False
        else:
            word += c


print(word_database)
```

It seems to work to a point where it reaches '\n' characters connected to open and close tag elements. I'll paste the start of the resulting array.

```
['<!DOCTYPE html>', '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class="no-js" lang="en">', '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class="no-js" lang="en">\n', '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html class="no-js" lang="en">\n',
```

As you can see the parsing is OK up until it reaches the '\n'. Can anyone explain why it isn't being ignored in the parser?

Comment: I assume you're doing this as a learning exercise, but in case you're not, the canonical solution for parsing HTML in Python is [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Not really, just seems as though that should solve my problem. I installed NLTK hoping that would solve the problem. Beautiful soup isn't working either.. perhaps I am not installing it correctly

Comment: So if it is not, you really should use Beautiful Soup. It worths to spend time trying to install an already done parser than making a new complete one.